# can't deploy a simple hello-world in lambda : problem with self-contained package

Tags: .net, aws-lambda

I am news to aws and to aws-lambda-cli. So I tried to make a simple Hello World following this article : http://www.philliphaydon.com/2017/03/15/part1-creating-a-good-old-hello-world-aws-csharp-lambda/ .
Only difference at the beginning : I did `$ dotnet new classlib -n HelloWorldLambda` instead of `$ dotnet new classlib -n HelloWorldLambda -f netcoreapp1.0` because I don't want to target this version.

For compiling, I use this command line : `dotnet lambda package`, then I upload the zip to my lambda and run the test. The CloudWatch logs show these lines :

```
"Failed to execute the Lambda function. The dotnet CLI failed to start with the provided deployment package.  Please check CloudWatch logs for this Lambda function to get detailed information about this failure.: LambdaException "
"Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a framework-dependent app, specify the appropriate framework in /var/task/lambda-synchro-qbo.runtimeconfig.json." 
"A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/var/task/'."
```

My lambda-synchro-qbo.runtimeconfig.json is at the root of the zip and contains this :

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netstandard2.0"
  }
}
```

I was suspecting that my package isn't self-contained  / portable but even if I compile like this `dotnet lambda package --msbuild-parameters "--self-contained"` I have the same problem.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Amaury

Answer (score 0):

I changed my target framework to `.Net Core 3.1` and that did the trick.

My `runtimeconfig.json` looks like this now:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "3.1.0"
    }
  }
}
```